# All the pages from search keyword is gone!

Tags: seo, keywords

Yesterday when i have checked me website's page ranking is search engine as per keywords, at that time it was perfect. But today when i was checking i found that mojority of keywords are not in top 100. I have attached one image. check it and answer me the reason...
[image]

I have only one question why it is happening? please help me...

Answer (score 2):

You really have to answer the question - "has Google penalised my website?"

To find the answer, you need to check whether Google has manually penalised your site and mentioned it in [Google Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools) (sign up if you haven't).

If there is no message from Google in there, you could of been hit by an [algorithmic update](http://searchenginewatch.com/article/2336544/Not-Ranking-in-Google-Is-a-Manual-Penalty-Algorithmic-Change-or-Content-to-Blame) and this will require checking whether your activity from an SEO perspective breaks Google's guidelines. I recommend reading Google's help section on SEO to understand this.

To be honest, I don't think you'll find more of a detailed answer unless you provide the URL of your website.